# Finding consecutive numbers in an array

Tags: java

I have been struggling to figure this out for the past 3 hours and i am frustrated as hell. If anyone can help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it. The program has to generate 10 random integers, then it has to print out the line of integers and group together the consecutive ones

Example:
4 3 3 4 0 0 1 3 0 4 4 5 2 2 5 4 5 1 2 2 
After Grouping:
4 (3 3) 4 (0 0) 1 3 0 (4 4) 5 (2 )2 5 4 5 1 (2 2)

Heres is my code

```
package week6assignments;

import java.util.Random;

public class Question2REal 

{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] rolls = new int[20];
    int input;
    int x = 1;
    boolean found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < rolls.length; i++) {
        input = rand.nextInt(6);
        rolls[i] = input;
    }

    System.out.println("Raw data output after 20 dice rolls");
    for (int i = 0; i < rolls.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(rolls[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Data after grouping runs together");

    for (int i = 0; i < rolls.length; i++) {
        ++x;
        if (x > 19) {
            x = 19;
        }
        if (rolls[i] == rolls[x] && found == false) {
            System.out.print("(");
            found = true;

            if (rolls[i] == rolls[x] && found == true) {
                System.out.print(rolls[i]);
            }
        }

        if (rolls[i] > rolls[x] || rolls[i] < rolls[x] && found == true) {
            found = false;
        }
        System.out.print(rolls[i]);
    }
}
}
```

I know this program is way off what its supposed to do, but ive tried 100's of things I can think of and cant figure out or find an example online. :(

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: So you have an array and you want to surround every pair of numbers (note: consecutive doesn’t mean ‘same’) with parenthesis?

Comment: Asking someone to "fix your code" isn't a valid question here.  You need to read the link that @shmosel posted, and [edit] your question to turn it into a general "how do I do X" or "how do I fix Y" type of question that is actually answerable without just doing your work for you, and that will be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: Have you tried the good old paper approach, where you drew the array an find the logic to the problem ?

Comment: Why not use [ints()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-): `int[] tenRandomNumbers = random.ints(10, 0, 11).toArray();` <- Creates an array of 10 random integers in the range 0 to 10 inclusive.

Comment: @azurefrog Actually I do my own programming, but I spent 3 hours trying to figure it out and I couldn't. It's not like I just got lazy, threw it up here and I'm like "do my shit for me", I genuinely couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @PandaKingBeersy So, spend another 3 hours refactoring your code down into a [mcve] with a *specific* error, and ask a question about that, then.  If you're stuck on how to detect repeated elements in an array, get rid of everything in your code and question that isn't about that, and ask *that* question.  I get that you're frustrated, but that isn't a good reason to ignore the guidelines here on SO regarding how to ask questions.

Comment: @azurefrog I have this, 2 other projects and a final to study for in the span of 10 days. I don't really care xD I gave my honest situation, and asked for help. If you don't wanna help, don't comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am really confused with what you were trying to do there in your code (like you said, its way off) so forget about everything you already have in that last for-loop.

First, you are trying to figure out if the current number is the same as the next one to group them together. So something like this.

```
if (rolls[i] == rolls[i+1]) {
    System.out.print("(" + rolls[i]);
}
```

Now, in your question and example, it wasn't clear if in the situation where if there are more than 2 same number, what was the intended action. So I assumed you would include it in the group.

In that case, you make a while loop (inside the `if` and after the `print`) that checks if all the following numbers are the same.

```
i++;

while (rolls[i] == rolls[i+1]) {
    System.out.print(" " + rolls[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Finally, we've always been printing the last number and not the current number so if the next one is no longer the same as the current, it will exit the while loop and we have to print the current number with a close bracket. So something like this...

```
System.out.print(" " + rolls[i] + ") ");
```

Now let's take care of else condition. Simple, just print the number and move on...

```
} else {
    System.out.print(rolls[i] + " ");
}
```

Of course, this isn't perfect, there are still a few edge cases that you need to work on. What if the while loop loops through the last item? Now we have an ArrayIndexOutOfBound. So here's a little tweak...

```
while ((i+1) < rolls.length && rolls[i] == rolls[i+1])
```

But then what about the first `if` during the last for-loop iteration? Probably need the same fix...

```
if ((i+1) < rolls.length && rolls[i] == rolls[i+1])
```

I've basically done all the work and thinking for you. If you understood what I explained, you should be able to put these pieces together rather easily.

Comment: Thank you! I worked it into my code and figured it out! I know all the functions you gave me, was just having a hard time using them to accomplish the goal. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -4):

Homework is ready. ;)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Homework {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();

        Integer last = null;
        boolean equals = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            int newInteger = rand.nextInt(6);

            if(Integer.valueOf(newInteger).equals(last)) {

                if(!equals) System.out.print("( ");

                equals = true;

                System.out.print(last+" ");

            } else {

                if(last != null) System.out.print(last+" ");

                if(equals) System.out.print(") ");

                equals = false;

            }

            last = newInteger;

        }

        System.out.print(last);

        if(equals) System.out.print(" )");

    }

}
```

Comment: Love how you get downvoted for actually helping me instead of complaining xD Thank you, I've been struggling for hours. I probably won't copy your exact code but its still helpful!

Comment: @PandaKingBeersy No problem ;) Life is good. Maybe just accept it as a response, so I get some points.